# IE 8 CSS problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, font-face

My website is looking fine on IE9, but not on IE8. The Davideugenepeterson class and id is not working. Can anyone point out where the problem is coming from?
Here's my CSS:

```
   @charset "utf-8";

body
{ min-width:839px;
  max-width:none;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  background-color:#fff; }

#Container
{ margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto; }

  #Banner
{ position:relative;
  background-color:#000;
  height:37px;
  width:auto;
  z-index:1; }

    #Theportfolioof
{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:170px;
  height:37px;
  left:-192px;
  top:9.4px;
  bottom:0;
  right:0px; }

.Theportfolioof
{ white-space:nowrap;
  color:#888888;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing:1.3px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  word-spacing:5px;
  line-height:3px;
  font:normal 21px "Quaver Sans";
  font-weight:100;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:visible;
  z-index:1; }

 #Davideugenepeterson
{ position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:170px;
  height:37px;
  left:182px;
  top:1px;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px; }

.Davideugenepeterson
{ white-space:nowrap;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  letter-spacing:0.8px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  word-spacing:4px;
  line-height:3px;
  font :normal 18px "Pacifico";
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:100;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  overflow:visible;
  z-index:1; }




#Logo
{ width:117px;
  height:117px;
  background-image:url(images/logo.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:37px;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  z-index:1; }
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="Container">
    <div id="Banner"><div id="Theportfolioof" class="Theportfolioof">the portfolio of</div><div id="Davideugenepeterson" class="Davideugenepeterson">david eugene peterson</div></div>
    <div id="Logo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Here's the  IE9 browser screenshots: This is how it's supposed to look [image: IE9]

And here's the difference with IE8.
[image: IE8]

I've validated it with W3C, The css is valid for html 4.01 strict and the html is valid as well. Anyone know what the issue is? It's like it's not even recognizing my set font. (Yes all the fonts are installed correctly on my server)

Comment: Consider providing small sample... I doubt you need all that CSS and HTML to show the problem. Than it would be easier to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably testing it on different PCs. The one with IE 9 has Pacifico and Quaver Sans installed, the other one does not.

This is not how web fonts work. If you want to use a custom one, you must define `font-family` in CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
  src: url('fonts/myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('fonts/myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('fonts/myfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

where `url()` containes the path to the font relative to CSS file.

If you don't have font files in all of the formats above use [Font Squirell's `@font-face` generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). If you wonder do you really need all of them check [The New Bulletproof @Font-Face Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in one of the properties of your `.Davideugenepeterson` class:

```
font :normal 18px "Pacifico";
```

Should be:

```
font: normal 18px "Pacifico";
```

My bet is IE8's CSS parser is reading `"font "` (with the space) as the property name and not recognizing it.